# Single Sign On from custom app to ADB2C application

Tags: azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, azure-ad-b2c

I have a web application that needs to connect to a SaaS application that used ADB2C. Once user logs in to my web application and does to the third-part integrated pages they should be automatically authenticated in the SaaS application (given they have been authenticated in my web app).

By adding my web app into the third-party ADB2C OIDC provider will it work ? I am not able to figure out how users in my web app will be able to "pass-through" the other application (federation ?).

Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: Can you describe the relationship between your application and the SAAS application a little more? Is the SAAS application an API that you want to submit requests to? It seems more likely that you will have to make your application authenticate with an ID token generated by their IdP than getting them to trust your application.

Comment: The SaaS application will render the page in my applications iFrame . To clarify my applications UI will have a link , clicking on which will render the SaaS application report in an iFrame within my application UI. My application relies on db created user/password authentication of user while SaaS uses ADB2C . Appreciate your inputs.

Comment: I don't see how this is going to work. If you have some specific details that you have questions about - you may want to re-state your question, but I don't know a way to design what you're describing.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking time on it. Let me just clarify one more thing , both these applications are in our control and I am not assuming that 2 unrelated applications can communicate. What I am looking for is what changes do I have to make in my web application that currently used database, to be authenticated by ADB2C application and same in ADB2C application do I have to make any change (add custom policy etc) to be able to  identify the web application as one of the federated authentication.  ie setup a SSO between these 2 applications.